# run a jar file from another Java copied in system

Tags: java, windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have a Java copied in  location. This is not added in the JAVA_HOME so Java command will not work.

I want to run a jar file located in .

I tried this command :

start \javaw.exe -jar \abc.jar but it does not work because both the path contains spaces.

What should be the actual command to run it ?

Comment: Add quotes around the path namens

Comment: CD to the location where javaW.exe is located. And run javaW.exe -jar "path_of_jar/file_name.jar". Note for codes.

Comment: You could have googled for this before coming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with double quotes e.g.

```
"c:\\Program Files\\Java\\java.exe" -jar abc.jar
```

It takes care of the spaces in the path